# Load wavs into memory then play sounds asynchronously using Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

I'm writing a simple game, using C++ and the Win32 API. I'd like to load a few sound effects into memory during the initialisation phase (before the game starts). Then I want to be able to trigger those sounds asynchronously during the game.

I've researched a few posts that recommend mmlib, (PlaySound), this works but the examples seem to load from file each time, something like this:

```
PlaySound("rocket_launch.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

I'd like to load my sounds into memory at the start, then play them whenever. Hopefully I won't need to use a resource file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PlaySound` [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) say to pass in `SND_MEMORY` to indicate that the first parameter points to a memory buffer.

So first, load the file into memory, and then pass in the pointer to the buffer, and swap out the `SND_FILENAME` flag for the `SND_MEMORY` flag.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at that. It describes loading from resource which I'd rather not do if possible! I was thinking maybe there's a simpler way to just load a wav, then play it?

Comment: @SimonBosley `SND_RESOURCE` comes from a resource, `SND_MEMORY` comes from memory.

Comment: @SimonBosley You don't need to load as a resource...  [here is a code sample](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/88542/#msg475470) that loads the wav from a normal file and plays it from the memory buffer.

Comment: @JonathanPotter the examples that I found that use SND_MEMORY have already loaded the file from resource (LoadResource) in the first place, which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Buddy I was originally put off that page by some of the comments remarking that files didn't play as expected. Looks to be what I need though, I'll give it a go and see how it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for a simple example:

```
std::string sound = "RIFFªÛ\x5....."; //(Binary of a .wav file)
PlaySoundA(sound.c_str(), NULL, SND_MEMORY | SND_SYNC); //Extracting the binary to a c-style string & playing
```