# How to play Wav byte arrays using c++

Tags: c++, audio, wav

i have a byte array like this "0x04, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00"
that is from a wav file that ive converted i believe without the headers

and i cant find any way online to be able to play the sound using windows functions

im needing these byte arrays to be hardcoded within the program i cant save it as an external file
because of the way my program is being used by the user

i have already looked through many windows api functions and none of them seem to be able to process and array of bytes to play sound

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320825/load-wavs-into-memory-then-play-sounds-asynchronously-using-win32-api) discusses how to play a wav from memory, but I am not sure that method can handle the raw media chunks without header info.

Comment: It seems playing them from resources seems to work on c# but im not sure if i can do the same on c++ but ill have more of a look now

Comment: @ConnorBilham: Resources have worked for 30 years. They're a native Windows capability, not specific to C# or C++. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/playing-wave-resources. To clarify: `hInst` in that example is the instance handle of the file which contains the sound, e.g. your EXE