# Play WAVEFORMAT/WAVEFORMATEX on C++ without generating any files

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, pcm, waveform

I'm programming pong using only C++ standard libraries (preferably Windows.h) and already finished developing everything.
The only problem i'm having is generating the sounds, all i can find is how generate and play .wav files.

Is there a way to generate a digital sound using something like WAVEFORMAT or WAVEFORMATEX and playing it during runtime without generating any files?
So far i only figured out how to declare de wave properties:

```cpp
const int sampleRate = 44100;
const int bits = 8;

int main()
{
    WAVEFORMAT format;

    format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    //format.wBitsPerSample = bits;
    format.nChannels = 1;
    format.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate;
    format.nAvgBytesPerSec = (sampleRate * bits)/8;
    format.nBlockAlign = bits/8;
    //format.cbSize = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: look at the Win32 `waveOut...` functions (`waveOutOpen()`, `waveOutPrepareHeader()`, `waveOutWrite()`, etc).  Read [Waveform Audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/waveform-audio) on MSDN for more details.  Though, in your case, I would suggest simply embedding `.wav` files into your game's resources, and then playing those resources when needed. You don't need to ship separate `.wav` files with your game

Comment: Just in case there is confusion rather than a wee bit of dodgy grammar, Windows.h **is not** part of the C++ Standard library.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "without generating any files"? Are you asking how to algorithmically generate the actual sound data? Or are you asking how to embed a sound file inside an `.exe` file, so that you don't have any additional files besides the `.exe` file? Or are saying that you have sound data in memory (not as a file) and that you are looking for a way to play that data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320825/load-wavs-into-memory-then-play-sounds-asynchronously-using-win32-api

Comment: _Is there a way to generate a digital sound_ There are lots of ways, please clarify what it is exactly that you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i kind of a mix of the first two things. I wish to generate the sound data and play it through the code itself with no usage of any external files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau using external .wav files would break the whole purpose of what i'm trying to do. I wish to make a simple game in the lowest programming level possible. And that includes synthesizing all the sounds via code

Comment: I suggest you could try to use the [PlaySound function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd743680(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with `SND_MEMORY` to play a sound that is stored as a resource.

Comment: Do you want to generate waveform audio? Or would [MIDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/musical-instrument-digital-interface--midi) be sufficient?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel depends. what is the difference between them and how can i do it?

Comment: @CaioLedo: In order to generate waveform audio, you must generate the actual sound wave, whereas with MIDI, you only need to specify an instrument and the notes, and it will automatically generate the sound wave for you. At least that is my understanding, I don't have any actual experience with MIDI.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i think i'll stick to waveform, since MIDI seems more high-level. my wish is just to generate an 8bit beep through code and i already know to put all the specifications for the soundwave. i just need to play it inside the code itself

Comment: @CaioLedo: "i already know to put all the specifications for the soundwave" -- What exactly do you mean with "specifications"? Do you mean that you are able to set the metadata such as sample rate, sample size and number of channels? Or are you saying that you are also able to generate the actual sound data (i.e. the sound wave)?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel both. but i only know how to generate .wav files with them. what i wanna do is play a sound through code without using any aditional files, if that's possible

Comment: @CaioLedo: Based on the information that you provided, I believe it would be best to embed your WAV files in your executable as a resource, and play the sound using `PlaySound`, as has already been suggested by someone else. That way, you will only need an external WAV file at compile-time, but not at run-time. See this link for further information: [Playing WAVE Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/playing-wave-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN) However, I believe one disadvantage of using `PlaySound` is that you can only play one sound at once.